# How to bind a sub-Property of an object in a different UserControl from the same ICollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using MVVM and would like to bind Car.Name to a `ListBox` and bind `CarDetailsList` to a `ListView` using `GridView`.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

There is a `Model`:

```
public class Car : ObservableObject  // ObservableObject simply means that this object is subject to PropertyChanged notifications.
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _name, value); }
        }     

        private List<CarDetail> _carDetailsList;
        public List<CarDetail> CarDetailsList
        {
            get { return _carDetailsList; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _carDetailsList, value); }
        }

        // CarDetail makes up a list of properties for the object Car for each "Name"
        public class CarDetail: ObservableObject
        {
            private string _engineType;
            public string EngineType
            {
                get { return _engineType; }
                set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _engineType, value); }
            }

            private string _color;
            public string Color
            {
                get { return _color; }
                set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _color, value); }
            }           
        }
    }
```

The `ViewModel` contains the following:

An `ObservableCollection` called `Cars`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
```

`ICommands`:

```
public ICommand SaveCarNameCommand { get; private set; }
public ICommand SaveCarDetailCommand { get; private set; }
```

An `ICollectionView`:

```
 private ICollectionView _carView;
        public ICollectionView CarView
        {
            get { return _carView; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _carView, value); }
        }
```

Two Properties:

```
private Car _selectedCar;
    public Car SelectedCar
    {
        get { return _selectedCar; }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(ref _selectedCar, value);
        }
    }
       private Car _selectedCarDetail;
    public Car SelectedCarDetial
    {
        get { return _selectedCarDetail; }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(ref _selectedCarDetail, value);
        }
    }
```

A Contructor:

```
public CarsForSaleViewModel()
{
    Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
    CarView = (CollectionView)new CollectionViewSource { Source = Cars }.View;
    OnPropertyChanged("CarView");
    SaveCarCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveCar);
    SaveCarDetailCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveCarDetail);
    SelectedCar = Cars[0]; //Selects the first Car        
}
```

`ICommand` Actions:

```
private void SaveCarDetail()
        {
            var newCarDetail = new Car.CarDetail
            {
                EngineType = SelectedCarDetial.EngineType,
                Color = SelectedCarDetial.Color               
            };
            // Add newCarDetail to CarDetailsList of "SelectedCar" in "DetailsList"
            SelectedCar.CarDetailsList.Add(newCarDetail); 
            CarView.Refresh();
            SelectedCarDetial = newCarDetail; // Selects the newly added item in the list
        }
        
        private void CarSave()
        {
            var newCar = new Car
            {
                Name = SelectedCar.Name,
                CarDetailsList = new List<Car.CarDetail>()
            };
          
            Cars.Add(newCar); // Add newCar to "CarList"
            CarView.Refresh();
            SelectedCar = newCar; // Selects the newly added item in the list
        }
```

I have a `View` called "CarsForSaleView" with three (3) `UserControls`.

The first `UserControl` "CarView" displays all the `Cars` by Name.

```
<ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
ItemsSource="{Binding CarView}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The second `Usercontrol` "DetailsView" displays the details of the `SelectedCar` in "CarsList".

```
<ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelcetedCar.CarDetailsList}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCarDetial}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Engine Type">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding EngineType}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Color">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Color}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The third `UserControl` "SaveCarView" allows the user to enter a `Name` in a `TextBox`, which is bound to the `Name` property.  When I click save, the "CarsList" is updated with a new Item bearing the Name the user enters.  Works great!

The forth `UserControl` "SaveCarDetailView" allows the user to select the `EngineType` and `Color` of the `SelectedCar` via ComboBoxes, each of which are bound to the respective `CarDetail` property.  When I click save, the item is added to the "DetailsList", but it is not visible until the user selects on a different "Car" in "CarsList" and then selects the "Car" which just had Detials added to the "DetailsList".

What is the proper means of binding the `ItemsSource` on "DetailsView" to the "SelectedCar" in the "CarView" ICollecitonView so that it refreshes when adding Details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of searching through multiple "similar" posts, I have solved this issue by changing "CarDetailList" from a `List<CarDetail`> to an `ObservableCollection<CarDetail>`.  Hope this helps someone with a similar `Model`.

```
 private ObservableCollection<CarDetail> _carDetailsList;
    public ObservableCollection<CarDetail> CarDetailsList
    {
        get { return _carDetailsList; }
        set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _carDetailsList, value); }
    }
```

and the SaveCar `ICommand` action:

```
 private void CarSave()
        {
            var newCar = new Car
            {
                Name = SelectedCar.Name,
                CarDetailsList = new List<Car.CarDetail>()
            };
          
            Cars.Add(newCar); // Add newCar to "CarList"
            CarView.Refresh();
            SelectedCar = newCar; // Selects the newly added item in the list
        }
```